# Why setting value to a function's argument affects the input variable when iterated but not when used as vector?

Tags: python, numpy

I'll appreciate an explanation to the different results. I've written a simple code to pinpoint my question:

```
import numpy as np

def mulby2_v1(x):
    x = x * 2
    return(x)

def mulby2_v2(x):
    for idx in range(len(x)):
        x[idx] = x[idx] * 2
    return(x)


vecin = np.ones(10,)
vecout = mulby2_v1(vecin)
print('v1:\n',np.vstack([vecin, vecout]))

print('--------------------')

vecin = np.ones(10,)
vecout = mulby2_v2(vecin)
print('v2:\n',np.vstack([vecin, vecout]))
```

Which result with

```
v1:
 [[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]]
--------------------
v2:
 [[ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]]
```

The input vector itself is modified in v2 but not in v1. Now why resetting a variable by index change the input while multiplying the whole vecotr by a scalar does not?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with vectors or scalars. In the first instance, you rebind the name `x` to point to something else; in the second, you mutate the existing object attached to `x`.

Comment: if you change something by assignment `x = x*2` it overrides the **local** variable where as modifying it in place `x[...] = ...` will modify the object.. well in place.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Thanks. I think I see the light... As a follow-up question: suppose I want to use my v2 approach (a for loop iterating over indices). What is the proper way to set a local copy of x so the input object will not be affected?

Comment: For a simple array use something like `x_out = x.copy()`. But watch out for deep and shallow copies. Nevermind, `np.copy` should be safe for numerical arrays.